# How to get an ITIN if I don't have passport?

Tags: united-states, taxes, itin

I'm new to investment. I never have any experience in stock investment. I'm not US citizen.

I tried to make an account with online brokerage like sharebuilder, and it asked me for a SSN number. I googled and found that I need to have ITIN if I am not US citizen.

In http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc857.html, I read that I need to fill in form W-7 to have ITIN, but along with the form, I need to submit identity documents, and either a federal tax return, or other documentation to show the federal tax purpose for which I need the ITIN.

For identity documents, may I just use a copy of my national id card?

I'm not sure what other documentation is here. I don't have a passport. Could somebody please give me an example of that documentation?

Do I have to pay for having ITIN? If I do, how much?

Comment: If you would read the information in the link you provided, it says "In addition to a passport, **examples of acceptable documentation include: national identification card (showing photo, name, current address, date of birth and expiration date);** civil birth certificate; foreign driver's license; or visa. A complete list of acceptable documentation can be found in the instructions to the Form W-7. **The documents must be originals or certified copies.**" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 1):

On the IRS site [you can find a list](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Acceptance-Agent-Program) of "acceptance agents" in your country. Talk to one of them, they'll deal with the IRS on your behalf. If you don't have any in your country, you can contact the big-4 accounting firms or any other agent elsewhere to provide you service. I'd suggest doing this through an agent.

Comment: Thx a lot for the reply littleadv.